# the behavior of $\tan(x)$ as $x$ goes to $0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Recently I answer a question with limits, in the question i got expression involving a lot of $\tan$'s and $x$'s$\left(\text{the question: }\lim_{x\to0}-\dfrac{\tan\left(x\right)-x\sec^2\left(x\right)}{2x^2\tan\left(x\right)}\right)$  when I used L'Hôpital's rule I noticed that if I replace some $\tan$ in $x$ the result won't change, I thought that maybe it is because when lim to $0$ both of them are equal, but after I checked it I got that only if the $\tan$ is multiply by an $x$.

after that i checked this over a lot of different limits to $0$ and I got the same at everyone, if i have $\tan x$ multiply by $x$ changing that $\tan x$ into 
$x$ wont change the answer. was I really unlucky in the limits i chose or is there an explanation to this?

Comment: Hint: $$x<\tan(x)<x+x^2,\quad x\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be understood in terms of the *series expansion* of the tangent function:

$$ \tan x = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{2}{15}x^5 + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \cdots\qquad \text{for } |x| < \frac{\pi}{2} $$
where the "$\cdots$" stands for terms involving higher powers of $x$.

When $x$ is close to $0$, a term with a high power of $x$ will be vanishingly small compared to earlier terms, so the *limiting behavior* of the function near $0$ depends only on the first term, $x$ -- unless something happens to cancel out that $x$ such that the next higher terms become visible.

In your example, this cancellation does indeed happen in the numerator $\tan(x)-x\sec^2(x)$, so if you replace that by $x-x\sec^2(x)$, the limit ought to change. But there is no cancellation in the denominator, so there you could have $2x^3$ or $2\tan^3(x)$ instead without any change.